# exclusion with combinatrics?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

> Suppose an a x b grid, and you start at the lower left corner and go to the upper right corner by
>   moving only up and right.
>   Suppose that a = 30, b = 40 and you cannot travel through the intersections (2, 3) and (12, 17). How many
>   possible paths are there?

What my Approach was, and where I was stuck was:

number total number of possibilities without the exclusion, is

$a+b-2 \choose a-1$ = $30+40-2 \choose 30-1$ = $68 \choose 29$

but what I don't know is that how would I find the possibility where the point passes through that point, then I can just subtract those possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good starting point and idea, inclusion and exclusion seems like the right tool. Let me build on what you think.

Guide:

- To compute the number of path that passes through $(2,3)$, you just have to count the number of path from $(0,0)$ to $(2,3)$ and then multiply by the number of path from $(2,3)$ to $(30,40)$.
- To compute the number of path that passes through $(12,17)$, you just have to count the number of path from $(0,0)$ to $(12,17)$ and then multiply by the number of path from $(12,17)$ to $(30,40)$.
- To compute the number of path that passes through both $(2,3)$ and $(12,17)$, you just have to count the number of path from $(0,0)$ to $(2,3)$ and then multiply by the number of path from $(2,3)$ to $(12,17)$ and then multiply by the number of path from $(12,17)$ to $(30,40)$.

Comment: I literally thought of the same idea like 5 mins ago, and was about to ask if that method would work, but I guess I don't need to ask anymore. Thanks a lot though!  Also, after I find those ways, for (0,0) to (2,3)*(2,3)to (30,40) I just subtract those posibilities from my total posibilities ight???  One last thing, for finding paths from (2,3) to (30,40) I thought of using the same formula mentioned in my question, where a would be 30-2 and b would be 40-3, am I thinking right?

Comment: You want to subtract number of path that passes through $(2,3)$ or $(30,40)$, not subtract the sums of the three terms. The third case is meant to adjust for double counting. Use inclusion-exclusion principle. Yes, use the same formula.

Comment: No what I meant was the paths to 30,40 would be me totals paths and I subtract the paths [the number of path from (0,0) to (2,3) multiplied by the number of path from (2,3) to (30,40)]

Comment: I made a typo in my previous comment, i meant subtract path that passes through $(2,3)$ or $(12,17)$. hmm... I think we still need to take $(12,17)$ into consideration.

Comment: yeah that's what U mean like subtract paths from both, (2,3) and (12,17) as they are kind of like cases so I was gonna subtract both, but I was just asking if I should subtract the product of(0,0) to (2,3) and  (2,3) to (30,40)

Comment: Let the quantity in the first sum be $A$, the quantity in the first sum be $B$, the quantity in the third sum be $C$. You should be subtracting $A+B-C$ from the total.

Comment: Sorry, but I am completely lost as to what are the sums A,B, C?

Comment: In my guide, there are $3$ points right, the first point is $A$, the second point is $B$, the third point is $C$.

Comment: ohhhhh, I see that makes sense. But I was wondering that can't I do like total possiblities $ Total= $$69\choose29$$ - A - B$ ??

Comment: $A$ is the number of paths that passes through first point. $B$ is the number of paths that passes through second point. Adding them together means double counting paths that passes through both of them which is the main idea behind inclusion exclusion principle.

Comment: Ohhh Right!!, so wait would it be $ Total= $$69\choose29$$ - (A + B - C)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75228/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-agent-smith).